# What File Transferring Method (i.e. FTP) Can I Use for rlogin (Solaris 8 on SPARC)

Tags: solaris, virtual-machine, putty

For all my other Unix Virtual Machines, I use `SSH` and I use WinSCP to transfer files from my Windows Vista machine to the VM's.

Now, One of the VM's is using `rlogin`, **What can I use to transfer files from my machine to the VM?**

I use PuTTY to connect remotely to the machine, but through `rlogin`.

Please can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The subject is a little confusing since *FTP* is usually not considered a description, abbreviating what it abbreviates, but signifies [a specific network protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP).  Btw, some Windows version apparently ship `rcp`, `scp`'s naked (I mean, unencrypted) brother.

Comment: is the title better? I'm looking at rcp now, but is talking about: `Copies files between a Windows XP computer and a system running rshd.` I don't have `ssh` or `rsh` on this machine, only `rlogin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I had a discussion with my colleagues, and they suggested I use NFS (Network File System), and am connecting WinSCP through another machine (Linux Server). It is all complicated but is working now.